# Error when merging typescript interface function declaration(Merging Interfaces)

Tags: typescript

```
interface Dog {
    speak(words: string): string;
}

interface Dog {
    speak(num: number): number;
}

const dog: Dog = {
    speak(wordsOrNum): string | number {
        return wordsOrNum;
    }
}
```

Interfaces are implemented as in the example code above, and declarations are merged.

However, when I try to implement a function in an object, an error occurs. Is this part possible?

[image]

Comment: Try to use `wordsOrNum: unknown` in the implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it work you should assure TypeScript that input value is equal to return value:

```js
interface Dog {
    speak(words: string): string;
}

interface Dog {
    speak(num: number): number;
}

const dog: Dog = {
    speak<Input extends string | number>(wordsOrNum: Input): Input {
        return wordsOrNum;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wjkv8N)

According to your type definition `speak(wordsOrNum): string | number` `wordsOrNum` might be a `number` and return type might be a `string` or vice versa

Comment: You are using generics. It seems like a good way. thank you.

Comment: const dog: Dog = {
    speak<T extends Dog>(wordsOrNum:T): T {
        return wordsOrNum;
    }
}